# HyperV snapshots

Tags: wmi, hyper-v

If we use the WMI CreateSnapshot() of "Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService" class, does it make it an application-consistent snapshot ?
==> Suppose if vm contains the MSSQL/exchange. On using this function to create snapshot, does the application inside VM is consistent ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CreateSnapshot() takes a parameter "SnapshotSettings". Which class instance do we need to pass on? I am looking for supported win2k12 server API and classes for these question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt167918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The class is supported only with server 2016. This contains a parameter where application-consistent can be passed on.